# Synonym for "application"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, synonyms

I am looking for a synonym for the word *application* as in *mobile application*.

In Spanish I would use *programa* but I am not sure if English speakers would understand me if I use *program* to refer to an *application*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anybody technology-oriented would understand you. I use the words interchangeably all the time without any misunderstanding.

Some other words you might use are *app*, which has become very popular recently, and *executable*, though that might just refer to the main binary of the software.

Comment: This pretty much says it all.

Comment: App seems to have been adopted as term of choice for mobile software, so +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the word "**software**" because I think it can be interchangeable.

Comment: *software* is uncountable, so it may be harder to use as a replacement for *application* in some settings, e.g. "a mobile application".